# Replace character at string index

Tags: javascript

Why won't this code work for me below? Can't i reassign a value at a specific index in the string?

```
function replaceChar (str) {
  let i

  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == '-') {
      str[i] = ' '
    }
  }
  return str
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Strings are immutable in JavaScript. You have to create a *new* string instead:

```
str = str.substring(0, i) + ' ' + str.substring(i + 1);
```

If you're doing that a lot, you might convert the string to an array of characters, do the replacements, and then convert the array back into a string. Here's an ES2015+ example:

```js
function replaceChar(str) {
  return [...str].map(ch => ch === "-" ? " " : ch).join("");
}
console.log(replaceChar("testing-1-2-3"));
```

---

Your entire loop can be replaced by the [`replace` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
str = str.replace(/-/g, " ");
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are *immutable* in Javascript - you can't change individual characters. If you want to do something like that, you'll have to explicitly convert the string to an array first, perform your changes, and then join the array back into a string again:

```js
function replaceChar (str) {
  str = [...str];
  let i

  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == '-') {
      str[i] = ' '
    }
  }
  return str.join('');
}
console.log(replaceChar('foo-bar-baz'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()` and `join()` together. Split the string by `-` and join the array by `<space>`

```
str.split("-").join(" ");
```